# How to find what activemq-broker version is used by a spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, nexus

When I update spring-boot version to 2.6.4, I'm getting below error

```
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:jar:5.16.4 from/to code-group-public
```

In Nexus, the activemq-broker jar:5.16.4  is quarantined. So should I downgrade my spring boot version or is there an alternate way to solve this issue? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an ActiveMQ issue, but most likely isolated to the local environment in your organization. You need to contact your organization's Nexus administrators and find out why the file is quarantined in your organization's Nexus.

You could also try to upgrade to 5.17.1.

Comment: Is spring boot using embedded activemq? Can I override it? If so please tell how to override activemq?

Comment: spring boot does not embed activemq. when you include a 'starter', the starter will depend on a version of activemq. Check your maven dependency:tree (or equiv if you use gradle). You can then override the version by including activemq-broker with the version you specify as a dependency to your pom.xml